# mjn:famous package destroys my links

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, famo.us

When I use the `mjn:famous` package in my meteor application the links `<a></a>` only work when I do a long tap on mobile. fast tapping will route me to the page also but its refreshing the page and I don't want a refresh here. I also can't deactivate this behavior with.

```
preventDefault()
```

When I remove the package everything works like expected.

I´m also using the `famousviews` packages.

How to fix the reload on mobile? (Tested on iOS8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I´ve found a solution.

the problem is `mjn:famous` seems to produce the behavior. I´ve removed it and added `raix:famono` instead. Now it works like expected.

cheers